# Does the band gap increase or decrease in this case?

Tags: solid-state-physics

Suppose I deposit a thin layer of a material A (with band gap Ea, say) on a material B (having band gap Eb) to form the film AB. What will the band gap of AB be? Will it be equal to Ea or Eb? Or will it be lesser or greater than them?

Comment: Do you mean form an alloy of A and B, or is there a film of A on B? In either case, there is no particular reason to think that the band gap would be the gap of either material alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have distinct layers of material, they will each maintain their respective band gaps. Then you have a heterostructure, not a single “effective” band gap. There are caveats to this, for instance if the thin layer is strained due to a lattice mismatch with the other material, then the band gap within the thin layer will be modified somewhat but still distinct.

The physics of such a heterostructure is potentially complex, depending on the relative alignment of the bands and the types of excitations which exist.